# is it possible in PostgreSQL to make load balance for read processes

Tags: postgresql

I installed and configured PostgreSQL on two servers with hot_standby clustering (Master - Slave) by PostgreSQL 9.6.17 on ubuntu 16.04.12 / 64-bit, my main goal to achieve the load balance for read processes in order to lessen the headache on one database server and make the reading data process faster.

What is the best solution for my case SQL Relay or Pgpool-II or what ? and there is any tutorial "step-by-step" to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Pgpool-II provides the best out of box solution for load balancing the read load on the PostgreSQL cluster. And enabling the load balancing is as simple as setting the `load_balance_mode = on` in pgpool.conf file.

https://www.pgpool.net/docs/41/en/html/runtime-config-load-balancing.html